# JavaScript массивы

Tags: javascript

Помогите реолизовать функцию getDivisors, которая параметром будет принимать число и возвращать массив его делителей, то есть чисел, на которое делится наше число. К примеру, если мы передадим число 24 - мы должны получить массив [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12, 24].

```js
function getDivisors(digit) {
  var sum1 = 0;
  for (elem of digit) {
    sum1 = sum1 + elem;
  }
  return sum1;
}
alert(getDivisors(26));
```

Comment: "Помогите" в данном случае означаeт "реолизовать" за Вас?

Comment: да, я попытался у меня не получился

Comment: Где Ваши попытки? Джентльменам верят на слово?

Comment: // function getDivisors(digit) {
 //  var sum1 = 0;
 //  for(elem of digit) {
 //   sum1 = sum1 + elem;
 //  }
 //  return sum1;
 // }
 // alert(getDivisors(26));

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var digit = '123'; // Ваше число
    function getDivisors(digit) {
        let array = [1];
        for (let i = 2, limit = digit >> 1; i <= limit; ++i) {
            if (!(digit % i)) array.push(i);
        }
        if (digit !== 1)
            array.push(digit);
        return array;
    }

    console.log(getDivisors(digit));
```

Comment: зачем делить на 2, если нужно корень извлекать, чтобы уменьшить количество проверяемых чисел?

Comment: @Grundy Потому что тогда надо добавлять в массив два числа на каждой итерации, а потом сортировать?

Comment: @Igor, а сортировать зачем? :) В принципе можно с помощью splice в центр вставлять и все

Comment: @Denis640Kb, зачем разделять? сразу вставлять

Comment: @Grundy Да, уже понял. Сейчас поем и попробую ) Спасибо.

Comment: Еще вариант, складывать в два массива - первая половина и вторая, потом их просто конкатенировать

Comment: @Grundy я тут попробовал пошаманить с извлечением корней... но у меня не хватило мозгов, как оно должно работать... и вот вопрос, как?))))

Comment: @Руслан, не корней, а корня, в том месте где вы оба делаете деление на 2, ты вызываешь `Math.sqrt` - дальше почти тоже самое что и сейчас, просто ты получаешь сразу два делителя а не один, например сейчас найдя что число 123 делится на 3, мы автоматически знаем, что оно делится и на 41

Answer (score 0):

Вот как по мне более интересный и простой вариант =)))

```js
function getDivisors(digit) {
 var denominators = [];
 var interimDenominators = 1;
 do {
  if(digit % interimDenominators == 0) {
   denominators.push(interimDenominators);
  }
  interimDenominators++;
 } while (interimDenominators <= digit / 2);
 denominators.push(digit);
 return denominators;
}

console.log(getDivisors(24));
console.log(getDivisors(123));
console.log(getDivisors(33));
```

Comment: более простой по сравнению с чем?

Comment: Хочу скачать пооблогодарить но GitHub не позволяет (

Comment: @СуроЗакарян Что?

Comment: Пожалуйста объясните мне этот кусок кода что он делает do {
  if(digit % interimDenominators == 0) {
   denominators.push(interimDenominators);
  }
  interimDenominators++;